# Velocity of a particle in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

The equations $r = 3\sin(2\theta)$ and $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = 2$ describe the motion of a particle in polar coordinates. Find the velocity of the particle in terms of the unit vectors $u_r$ and $u_\theta$. Sketch the path of the particle.

I don't understand how to relate the unit vectors to the position function or how to use $\frac{d\theta}{dt}. $

Comment: The position of the particle is $\vec r=r\vec u_r$. Use the relation $\frac{\mathrm d\vec u_r}{\mathrm d\theta}=\vec u_\theta$ and the chain rule.

Comment: I'm still not totally clear. I have the $r$ equation, but not $\vec{r}$. When I use the relation, I get that $\theta = 2t$ but am not sure how this helps me.

Comment: Comments are too short for a detailed explanation, so I posted as an answer. By the way, you have $\theta(t)=2t+\mathrm{C^{st}}$.

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates, the radial unit vector is $$\vec u_r(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}.$$ Therefore a point located at radius $r$ and angle $\theta$ is located at the point of coordinates $\vec r=\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}$. We have the relation $\boxed{\vec r=r\vec u_r(\theta)}$.

The motion of the particle is described by $r(\theta)=3\sin(2\theta)$ that is as function of time $r(t)=3\sin(2\theta(t)).$ The position is therefore
$$\vec r(t)=r(t)\,\vec u_r(\theta(t)).$$
Now take the derivative of this expression using the definition (1) and note that the derivative of $\vec u_r$ is
$$ \frac{\mathrm d\vec u_r}{\mathrm d\theta}(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}-\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}=\vec u_\theta(\theta).$$
This last formula will enter into play in $\frac{\mathrm d\vec u_r(\theta(t))}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\mathrm d\theta(t)}{\mathrm dt}\;\vec u_\theta(\theta(t))$.

Comment: can you walk me through this with the values so I get a more concrete understanding? I'm pretty confused. thanks

Comment: The velocity is $\vec v=\mathrm d\vec r/\mathrm dt$. This gives, using the chain rule, $\vec v=(\mathrm dr/\mathrm dt)\vec u_r+r\vec u_\theta\mathrm d\theta/\mathrm dt$. Use $\mathrm d r/\mathrm d t=(\mathrm d\theta/\mathrm dt)\times 6\sin(2\theta)$, and you should reach the final result y putting everything together.